# Why won't gnupg be fooled by my pseudoterminal trick?

Tags: gnupg, terminal

Gnupg requires many of its inputs to come literally from a terminal instead of just stdin.

I sometimes can get around that with:

**pty-run**:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"
exec script --quiet --return -f --command "$cmd" /dev/null
```

And then

```
$ { echo my-input; } | pty-run the-gpg-command
```

For example, I can assign a certain level of trust, noninteractively, with to a certain set of keys with:

```
marginal=3
for k in "${keyset[@]}"; do printf '%s\n' trust "$marginal" save | pty-run gpg --edit-key "$k"; done
```

But this fails when passwords are required even when I do provide the passwords on the stdin.

My naive emulation of what I think the-gpg-command should be doing :

```
printf '%s\n' A B | pty-run bash -c ' read -s a < /dev/tty; read -s b </dev/tty; echo a=$a b=$b; '
```

works (i.e., with `pty-run`, `a` and `b` get assigned from stdin even when the bash script reads directly from the controlling terminal).

What is gnupg doing that prevents this from working and how can I figure it out?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here. This is about the inner workings of how a particular binary interprets input. Despite it being about gpg, it's not actually a security question.

Comment: In version 2 (at least?) `gpg` itself doesn't prompt for the passphrase; it first tries to open `gpg-agent` if that is already running and if not starts it; it then queries `gpg-agent` and a pre-running one may have the password cached but a new one doesn't, in which case `gpg-agent` runs a `pinentry` program which uses X if possible and otherwise the tty (but I don't know exactly how) -- but I've never seen a `script` with long options like that, and you tagged 'terminal', so I'm guessing you're on MacOSX, which may be different anyway. ...

Comment: ... Rather than get in the middle of that mess, *I* would give the passphrase to `gpg` directly and not try to feed it through the pty, but that's not your question. If it were, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60213/gpg-asks-for-password-even-with-passphrase might solve it, as it did for me.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks. Tagged it "terminal" but meant "pty".  security.stackexchange.com didn't have that tag.